# Dynamic text inside ionic tabs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic tab, Example:

```
  <ion-tab title="Network" icon-off="ion-person-stalker" icon-on="ion-person-stalker" href="#/tab/network">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-network"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

That shows the proper icon depending on the icon-off and icon-on attribute.

Is there anyway to insert a number or dynamic content inside the tab instead of the icon?

Comment: Just came back across this today, did the below solution work for you or did you find a different way?

Answer (score 3):

What I have done is just place my dynamic content inside the title attribute.  So in your case if you wanted "Network 5" the html would look like:

```
<ion-tab title="Network {{model.tabBinding}}" icon-off="ion-person-stalker" icon-on="ion-person-stalker" href="#/tab/network">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-network"></ion-nav-view></ion-tab>
```

and the JavaScript controller:

```
$scope.model = { tabBinding: 5 }
```

**UPDATE**
Last week I answered a separate question which is somewhat related and could help depending on how your (anybody's) tabs are set up.  The other question is about disabling a tab, but the same example could be used to supply additional content to the tab.

[Dynamically Enable a Disabled Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468727/how-to-dynamically-enable-a-disabled-ion-tab/37469489#37469489)